Find command with -regex option using caret have unexpected behaviour
I would like to run the find command and get some of the files/directories in the desktop directory using regex option of the command with the symbol caret ^
As you know the caret ^ matches the beginning of a line, and I would like to get all the files/directories starting with the letter t; I used the following command find . -regex "^./t", but as it turned out, it will only match the file/folder whose name is a simple t!
I know that the regex will match the whole path and not only the file name. But why all of these do not match since they start with ./t.
./tcpdump.txt
./t.txt
./test.sh
./trade.txt
./torbrowser.desktop
./token.txt

PS: This regex worked for me, ^./t.*, but still unable to understand the behavior of caret in the original command

The -regex option expects a pattern that matches the entire path. See man find:

-regex pattern
File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a
match on the whole path, not a search.  For example,  to  match a
file named ./fubar3, you can use the regular expression  ‘.*bar.'
or  ‘.*b.*3',  but not ‘f.*r3'.  The  regular expressions understood
by find  are  by  default  Emacs  Regular Expressions, but this can be
changed with  the -regextype option.

The caret is pointless in this context since as explained above, the -regex will have to match everything, so essentially, the ^ and $ are implied.
You gave it ^./t which means "look for any character" (remember that the . means "any character" in regular expressions, it doesn't mean a literal .) followed by a / and then the single letter t and nothing else.
What you need here is the -name operand, which takes globs and not regular expressions, and only matches the file's name, not the entire path. So to find all files/dirs whose name begins with a t, use:
find . -name "t*"

The glob t* means "t followed by 0 or more characters". If you really want to do it with -regex, although that only makes it more complicated, you would need to specify that you allow anything to come after the t, like this:
find . -regex '.*/t.*'

That regex means "match as many characters as you can (including 0) until the last / and then a t followed by anything else.

Does this mean that the ^ will have no effect since it is also implied when using other commands that use regex as an option, like grep, for instance?

No, not at all @Starnec, it is just how find's -regex works, not a general feature of regular expressions. It just happens that, as explained in man find, the developers of find wrote the -regex operand so that it needs to match the entire path, and that makes the ^ and $ redundant. But it's only specific to find's -regex.

The fact that the regex always matches the whole path means the caret and dollar sign are redundant: The whole path must match, not just its substring. Or, you can always imagine the regex starts with a caret and ends with a dollar sign, even if you don't type them.

Do you mean that the caret is redundant?

@Starnec: Exactly. Thanks for the better wording.
